# Anaconda Navigator only shows Visual Studio Code

Tags: 18.04, anaconda

[Screenshot of Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALrTk.png)

I Installed Anaconda Navigator in 18.04.03 LTS Ubuntu. After the installation initialized the Navigator from terminal also. But after loading it shows only the Visual Studio Code. There is no Spyder,Jupyter,Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you installed anaconda as root with something like

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/Anaconda...
```

Then launched navigator without sudo

```
anaconda-navigator
```

*That's what I did to cause the same issue on my install anyway*

---

To fix this either allways run  in `sudo anaconda-navigator`, or remove the anaconda install with

```
sudo rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

and re-install **without** sudo.